# I want to change the price of the product then add to cart on the product listing page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using multi vender extension, in which this extension shows the multiple seller of the same products (ex : available from 2 more sellers) . I have shown in the drop-down of seller name with price for the particular product. Now I want to change the default product price with the listed seller price then add to cart the product.

Now I have changed the product price using jQuery, but when I add the product into the cart, it displaying the default price.

How can I achieve this.
[image]

I am using the below code for this :

```
<select class="select" id="seler-option-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" name="option" onchange="myseller('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>',this.value)" style="position: absolute;top: 15px; right: 25px;">
                            <option value="select<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>">select seller</option>
                            <?php $i=0; ?>
                            <?php foreach($sellerinfo as $sellerinfos){?>
                                <?php if($sellerinfos){?>
                                    <?php $explodestr = explode('seller',$sellerinfos)?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $_product->getId().$i; ?>"><?php echo $explodestr[0].' ($'.$explodestr[2].')'?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php $i++; } ?>
                        </select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function myseller(prdid, sellerId) {  

        jQuery('.seller-price-'+prdid+' ul li').each(function(){

            var selerprice = jQuery(this).attr('sellerprice');
            jQuery('.price'+selerprice).hide();
             if(sellerId == selerprice){
                jQuery('.price'+selerprice).show();
                jQuery('.seller-price-'+prdid).prev('.price-box').hide();
             }else if(sellerId == 'select'+prdid){
                jQuery('.seller-price-'+prdid).prev('.price-box').show();
             }
        });   

    }
</script>
```

Comment: create seller as custom options in admin

Comment: custom option but why ?

Comment: Vinod please conform "select seller" which is a drop down custom options for the product.?

Comment: no, there is not a custom option. I have listed all seller for the same product in the drop-down.

Comment: @vindod whether you aware of adding custom price to cart using observer "checkout_cart_product_add_after" ?

Comment: But price is available with each seller. And I want to use selected seller price  when add to cart.